# In-Memory database to handle Tree structure data

Tags: database, tree, hierarchical-data, in-memory-database

I am working on an application that stores hierarchical or Tree structure data and the database should be In-Memory. Can anyone suggest Open Source In-Memory database to store Tree data? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst) is an open source / dual licensed object-oriented embedded (not client/server) DBMS for Java and C# that can be in-memory.  (Disclosure: Perst is developed & supported by McObject, my employer.)